# Why does strcat() on a new string craps out undefined characters in the beginning while strcpy is ok?

Tags: c

For example

```
sprintf(pos,"%f ",cl.snap.ps.origin[0]); //don't start with strcat
sprintf(tmp,"%f ",cl.snap.ps.origin[1]);strcat(pos, tmp);
```

fine.

with

```
sprintf(tmp,"%f ",cl.snap.ps.origin[0]);strcat(pos, tmp);
sprintf(tmp,"%f ",cl.snap.ps.origin[1]);strcat(pos, tmp);
```

not fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `strcat()` function expects that the destination argument already contains a properly null-terminated string. In your case, it sounds like `pos` contains some junk that *looks* like a null-terminated string, but isn't what you expect. `strcat()` is dutifully appending on to the end of that junk.

One way to fix this is to initialise `pos` before your code:

```
pos[0] = '\0';
sprintf(tmp,"%f ",cl.snap.ps.origin[0]);strcat(pos, tmp);
sprintf(tmp,"%f ",cl.snap.ps.origin[1]);strcat(pos, tmp);
```

Comment: Another way: `sprintf(pos, "%f %f ", cl.snap.ps.origin[0], cl.snap.ps.origin[1]);`

Comment: "strcat() function expects that the destination argument already contains a ". Right, beautiful. Atrocious that manuals don't say that: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/ [or if they do, they do a good job at obscuring it]

Comment: From that page: "destination Pointer to the destination array, which should contain a C string".

Answer (score 3):

[`strcat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/) *concatenates* strings ; which means, it merges the contents of `pos` and `tmp`. What does `pos` contain before you call `strcat`? Has it been defined?

Comment: The problem (in documentation of sites such as this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/) is that concatenation doesn't mean "1st argument must have a terminating character". You have to explicitly know it. i.e. There's nothing saying that it can be undefined but there's nothing saying it can't be undefined either.


Of course I guess, one could go with the rule 'never touch anything even remotely undefined in c'. I guess they should start segfaulting stuff like declarations without definitions and then checking if they're untrue to be more concise..

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `strcat` and `tmp`. You're writing senselessly overcomplicated and inefficient code. Instead:

```
pos+=sprintf(pos,"%f ",cl.snap.ps.origin[0]);
pos+=sprintf(pos,"%f ",cl.snap.ps.origin[1]);
...
```

Unless you're sure `sprintf` cannot fail, rather than directly adding the return value to `pos`, you should probably first store the return value in a separate `int` variable and check that it's not -1.

It would also be better to use `snprintf` to make sure you don't overflow your buffer:

```
size_t cnt, rem=your_buffer_size;

cnt=snprintf(pos, rem,"%f ",cl.snap.ps.origin[0]);
if (cnt>=rem) goto error;
pos+=cnt; rem-=cnt;

cnt=snprintf(pos, rem,"%f ",cl.snap.ps.origin[1]);
if (cnt>=rem) goto error;
pos+=cnt; rem-=cnt;
...
```

Note that `cnt` being an unsigned type (`size_t`) is critical to the error check working.

Comment: Indeed. I was thinking more of a general pattern for cases where you can't do that.. perhaps when subsequent appends depend on the results of earlier ones or when you need to use the intermediate string - like testing that a directory is only accessible by the current user before creating a security-critical file in it or something.

Comment: Also, since your argument was an array element, it looked like you might actually want to put this code in a loop.